# mysql innodb deletes 10000 rows by primary key, but no index is used

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb, sql-delete

I have one `MySQL` table using the `InnoDB` storage engine. it contains about 8000000 data rows, When I used

```
delete from t where id in(1,2,3...)
```

to delete 10000 rows of data,It did not hint the primary key index although id is the primary key.The table t has `6 indexes（Including primary key）`.When I change the `SQL` to

```
select * from t where id in(1,2,3...)
```

It can hit the primary key index. When I reduce the number of parameters to delete 5000 rows of data,Or When I delete non-primary key index but still delete 10000 rows of data,It can also hit the primary key index.

The mysql version is 5.7.27.
The id to be deleted is selected according to specific conditions, not continuous.
when I try to keep two secondary indexes,Can still use the primary key index.

Why did not hit the index despite specifying the primary key value?

What is the relationship between the number of `deleted records` and the `secondary index`?

Comment: which mysql version? I suspect you've used `EXPLAIN {query}` - can you include it? are your `id`'s always sequential? Why not a range here? There is probably more context need around your last question around `deleted records` and `secondary index` need to understand this question. Welcome to SO

Comment: the version is 5.7.27

Comment: The id to be deleted is selected according to specific conditions, not continuous

Answer (score 1):

What version?  A newer version has changed the cutoff between two ways of dealing with a long `IN` list.

Older versions optimize `UPDATE` and `DELETE` differently than `SELECT`.

I don't like to tackle more than 1000 rows at a time.  Be aware that `DELETE` is a lot more complex than `SELECT`.  The old values of the rows are saved in case of `ROLLBACK` or recovery from a crash.

Where did you get the `ids`?  It might be better to leave them where they are, and do a multi-table delete to grab the ids from the source, instead of building the list.

For `SELECT` the cutoff between using a secondary index and doing a table scan is about 20% of the table.  The exact cutoff depends on the statistics and the "cost" computations.

Check out my other tips on big deletes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig